# How would I go about getting an exceeding amount of money overseas?

Tags: international-transfer

I'm trying to buy something overseas, but there is the possibility of being scammed in the processes (because it's from person to person). What is the safest instant way to transfer 35,000 USD to Germany from the United States?

Comment: Can you provide more information about what you are trying to do and what you are afraid might happen?

Comment: I also doubt there's anything that can make is "instant" - especially not with that large of an amount.

Answer (score 0):

If you trust the other party, an international bank wire would be the quickest, easiest, and cheapest option. It is the standard way to pay for something overseas from the United States. Unfortunately, in most cases, they are not reversible.

I don't believe Paypal is an option for an amount that large.  Escrow companies do exist, but you would have to research those on a case by case basis to see if any fit the criteria for your transaction and the countries involved.

**I'll also add:**

If it were me, and there was no way to get references or verify the person's identity and intent to my satisfaction, then I would probably consider hopping on a plane. For that amount of money, I would verify the person and items are legitimate, in person, and then wire the money.

Comment: I don't think he does trust the other party since he's worried about being scammed...

Comment: Obviously he should do his due diligence regardless.  And make a very educated decision as to whether or not to send the money, regardless of the transfer method. That said, at least with Germany you'd have some chance of tracking the person down.  In China, forget about it.